# Anchor to table on landscape page

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, links

I have a table (example below) which is wide and needs to be on a landscape page to display all the data, but when I run `\listoftables`, the link generated links to the bottom of the page instead of the top, making it look like the link is actually going to the next page.

```
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
            A & B & C & D & E & F & G \\
            \hline
            ...
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{tab:label}
    \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
```

I've also tried using `\begin{sidewaystable}`, but that has the same problem.

Oddly enough, it works fine when use the built-in preview in overleaf, but doesn't work when I export to a PDF.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I'd recommend using `sidewaystable` here rather than trying to put a float inside `landscape`. (`rotating` package.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel stupid.

Out of despiration I started messing with the options in overleaf, and changing Latex Live Version from 2017 to 2019 seems to have fixed the problem.